# Why is there a syntax error in my map iterator?

Tags: c++

I wrote a template function for flipping my `std::map` keys and values.

```
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

template <typename A, typename B>
std::map<B, A> flip_map(std::map<A, B> &src)
{
    std::map<B, A> dst;
    for (std::map<A, B>::iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
    {
        dst.insert(std::pair<B, A>(it->second, it->first));
    }
    return dst;
}
```

VS gives me a syntax error:

> unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Remember, `auto` is your friend.  Let it do the work for you.  `for (std::map<A, B>::iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)` -> `for (auto it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)` or better yet `for (auto e : dst)`

Comment: @NathanOliver Or, better yet, `for (auto e : src)`

Comment: The best one is: 
for (auto&[key, value] : src) {...}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GCC tells you more clearly what's wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15a4604f9e9958ee): you need `typename` there, for arcane C++ reasons.

Like this:

```
for (typename std::map<A, B>::iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
//   ^^^^^^^^
```

Further reading:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/560648)

---

I'd instead write it like this:

```
#include <map>

template <typename A, typename B>
std::map<B, A> flip_map(const std::map<A, B>& src)
{
    std::map<B, A> dst;

    for (const auto& p : src)
        dst.insert(std::make_pair(p.second, p.first));

    return dst;
}
```

In fact, as it happens, I did; two weeks ago. :)

*(You could also consider some `.emplace` and `std::move` etc, depending on what `A` and `B` are likely to be, though since you cannot move from a map key this is only ever going to be "sort of useful".)*

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `std::map<A,B>::iterator` is a dependent name (in rough terms, it is in a templated function, and depends on `A` and `B` which are parameters of that template).   So it needs to be preceded with the `typename` keyword.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::map<B, A> flip_map(std::map<A, B> &src)
{
    std::map<B, A> dst;
    for (typename std::map<A, B>::iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
    {
        dst.insert(std::pair<B, A>(it->second, it->first));
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Additionally you would probably be better specifying `src` as `const`, and using `const_iterator` rather than `iterator`, viz

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::map<B, A> flip_map(const std::map<A, B> &src)
{
    std::map<B, A> dst;
    for (typename std::map<A, B>::const_iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
    {
        dst.insert(std::pair<B, A>(it->second, it->first));
    }
    return dst;
}
```

or (C++11 and later), let the compiler do the type deduction for you by using `auto` and `std::make_pair`.  This avoids need for the programmer to worry about dependent names.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::map<B, A> flip_map(const std::map<A, B> &src)
{
    std::map<B, A> dst;
    for (const auto &e : src)
    {
        dst.insert(std::make_pair(e.second, e.first));
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a complete answer.